# How to Close and Unmount Bootstrap Modal with React.js Portals

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, modal-dialog

I am creating a modal to activates onClick from a row in a table. The modal will appear and display all the data that the table row contains. I have been able to get the modal to appear but I cannot close it after it mounts.

I thought the state was not updating because setState need a callback function to trigger it immediately but that does not work for me.

```
// Modal.js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

const modalRoot = document.getElementById('modal-root');

class Modal extends React.Component {
    el = document.createElement('div');

    componentDidMount() {
        modalRoot.appendChild(this.el);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        modalRoot.removeChild(this.el);
    }

    render() {
        // Use a portal to render the children into the element
        return ReactDOM.createPortal(
            <div className="modal fade show" id="exampleModal" tabIndex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static" style={{display: 'block'}} aria-modal="true">
                <div className="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div className="modal-content">
                        <div className="modal-header">
                            <h5 className="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                                <button onClick={ this.handleHide } type="button" className="close" aria-label="Close">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        <div className="modal-body">
                            { this.props.children }
                        </div>
                        <div className="modal-footer">
                            <button onClick={ this.props.onClose } type="button" className="btn btn-secondary">Close</button>
                            <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>,
        this.el);
    }
}

export default Modal

// FlightLogSummary.js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Modal from '../layout/Modal'

class FlightLogSummary extends React.Component {
    state = {showModal: false}

    handleShow = () => {
        this.setState({showModal: true});
    }

    handleHide = () => {
        this.setState({showModal: false});
    }

    render() {
        const { flightLog } = this.props

        const modal = this.state.showModal ? (
            <Modal>
                Modalidy
            </Modal>
        ) : null;

        return (
            <tr onClick={ this.handleShow }>
                <th scope="row">{ flightLog.flightDate }</th>
                <td>{ flightLog.flightRoute }</td>
                <td>{ flightLog.flightAircraft }</td>
                <td className="text-right">{ flightLog.flightTotal }</td>
                { modal }
            </tr>
        )
    }
}

export default FlightLogSummary;
```

The modal should be triggered by the onClick on the row. The modal should appear. When the close button for the modal is clicked it should disappear.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need createPortal for that, because the children are already passed as props. Just pass the onClose function to the Modal component.

I used a button here to toggle the modal component, but you can pass the onClick handle to the `tr` element as well.

Also, take advantage of the `setState` function parameter to update the state based on the previous state value.

```js
class Modal extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="modal fade show" id="exampleModal" tabIndex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static" style={{display: 'block'}} aria-modal="true">
        <div className="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div className="modal-content">
            <div className="modal-header">
              <h5 className="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
              <button onClick={this.props.onClose} type="button" className="close" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div className="modal-body">
              {this.props.children}
            </div>
            <div className="modal-footer">
              <button onClick={this.props.onClose} type="button" className="btn btn-secondary">Close</button>
              <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class FlightLogSummary extends React.Component {
    state = { showModal: false }

    toggleModal = () => {
      this.setState(prevState => ({ showModal: !prevState.showModal }))
    }

    render() {          
      return (
        <div>
          {/* <tr onClick={this.toggleModal}> ... </tr> */}
          <button onClick={this.toggleModal}>Toggle Modal</button>
          {this.state.showModal && <Modal onClose={this.toggleModal}>Modality</Modal>}
        </div>
      )
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought I had to use a Portal to make my Modal Component reusable? Plus it allows me to pass data down into the modal and place the modal in different parts of the application. I'm really new to React.js so I appreciate any and all advice.

Comment: The component is already reusable as it is. You can use in different parts of the app. 
You need to create a portal if you want to `render children into a DOM node that exists outside the DOM hierarchy of the parent component`. Then you'd need to pass the container component as a prop. But for this specific example, this is just fine.

Comment: But in my specific example I am using a table. I cannot have a <div> appear inside a <tr> so I need to render the modal somewhere else, so thats why I went for a Portal.

Comment: Oh I see! Yeah, then you're right. You can handle the close event inside the modal component. Use the portal and remove the modal component on the onClose event.

Comment: Cool cool. Good to know I'm on the right track. Now I've incorporated your toggle function and the this.props.onClose in the Modal. The Modal opens as it should but it won't close now. Still the same problem unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `modal` from react libraries for bootstrap. You can use modal from [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/) or [reactstrap](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/modals/). These libraries are more compatible with react.

Other than that, `handleHide` function is in `FlightLogSummary` and you are trying to access it in `Modal` component. You can to following:

```
<Modal close={this. handleHide}>
   Modalidy
</Modal>
// in Modal component
<button onClick={this.props.close} type="button" className="close" aria-label="Close">
  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
```

You can also add `console.log()` in `handleHide` function to check whether it is called or not.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried your suggestion but the modal is still not disappearing when I click close. I added a console.log and the the handleHide function is called, but no action.

Comment: Please try removing ‘createPortal’

Comment: Because all this is happening inside a table do I not need to Portal this Modal outside the <tr>. By removing the createPortal means I will be rendering a <div> within a table element.

Comment: I decided to go with react-bootsrap. I didn't realize that it created the modal in a portal automatically.

Comment: However, I am back to my same issue, I cannot close the modal after it opens. I have copied the exact code from the react-bootstrap site.